# Why is $\frac{\mathbb Z[x]}{(3,x^2+17)}\overset{\sim}{=}\frac{\mathbb F_3[x]}{(x^2-1)}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Why is $\displaystyle\frac{\mathbb Z[x]}{(3,x^2+17)}\overset{\sim}{=}\frac{\mathbb F_3[x]}{(x^2-1)}$ ?

Well $3$ in the first ideal reduces the coefficients of an element in $\mathbb Z[x]$ to $\mathbb F_3$, but what is the relation between the quadratic terms ?

Comment: $17 \equiv -1 \mod 3$?

Comment: Exactly. $x^2-1$ is an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_3$, since $-1$ is not a quadratic residue $\pmod{3}$, hence both your terms are finite fields with nine elements.